# how can implement mobile themes app in android

Tags: android, themes

i am developing one application in android ,in this app related to themes. select theme will effect entire os (entire mobile ) how can implement this functionality

please forward some valuable solution thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly view Google Shelves Project
http://code.google.com/p/shelves/
download the code from their repository.

Comment: hi aizaz this url not specify code download please forward any alternative sample my problem one theme select my app this theme apply in to total mobile (os)

Comment: You can only download code from SVN, you can use Eclipse with SubVersion or follow this link http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Comment: first download code from URL with the help of Eclipse and SVN plugin like SubVersion. you can get subversion for eclipse from this url http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

Comment: you can also consult Subversion tutorial at this url http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html sorry for late reply